# Get checked elements and seperate them with comma and last element with "and"

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

I want to get checked elements and seperate them with comma and last element with 'and'

its showing output as:

[image: Expected result]

I want to remove comma (,) after last element and add 'and' before it like

```
Sugar, Milk and Extra chocolate
```

or if two selected :

```
Sugar and Milk
```

My code:-

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Assignment1</title>
    <script>
     function genresult() {
      //Name
      var name=document.getElementById("cname").value;

      //Select drink
      var seldrink="";
      var drinks=document.getElementsByName("drink");
      for(var i = 0; i < drinks.length; i++)
      {
       if(drinks[i].checked) {
         seldrink=drinks[i].value;
         break;
        }
      }

    //Add ons
      var addons="";
      var addns=document.getElementsByName("addons");
      for(var i = 0; i < addns.length; i++)
      {
       if(addns[i].checked) {
         addons+=addns[i].value + ", " ;
      }
      }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = addons;

      //Payment mode
      var pay = document.getElementById("payment").value;

      var final= "<span>"+name+" </span> would like to have <span>"+seldrink+" </span> <br/>\
                    <span> With"+ addons +" </span> <br/>\
                    will pay by <span>"+pay+" </span>.";
      
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = final;
     }
    </script>
    <style>
    #result {
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
      background: #FAD160;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    #result span {
     color: #FFFFFF;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-decoration: underline;
      text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <table border="0" cellpadding="10" width="600" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h3>Order details</h3></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Enter you name</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="cname"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Select your drink</td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" id="coffee" name="drink" value="Coffee"/><label for="Coffee">Coffee</label>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
          <input type="radio" id="tea" name="drink" value="Tea"/><label for="Tea">Tea</label>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
          <input type="radio" id="chocolatedrink" name="Drink" value="Chocolatedrink"/><label for="chocolatedrink">Chocolatedrink</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>Select Add-ons</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="wsugar" name="addons" value="Sugar"/><label for="wsugar">With sugar</label>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
          <input type="checkbox" id="wmilk" name="addons" value="Milk"/><label for="wmilk">With milk</label>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
          <input type="checkbox" id="wchocolate" name="addons" value="Extra chocolate"/><label for="wchocolate">With extra chocolate</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Select payment mode</td>
        <td>
          <Select id="payment"/>
          <option>Credit card</option>
          <option>Debit card</option>
          <option>Cash</option>
          </Select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-btn" onclick="genresult();"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><p id="result">Order details as Below:</p></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: please add your code as well.

Comment: added code..thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use an array for this task.

First, collect all items in an array. Then get the two last elements and join them with `' and '` and put it as last element back into the array and later join all elements with `', '` for getting a nice string.

Methods

- [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), joins two arrays and returns a new array
- [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), for getting the last two elemensts of the array
- [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), joins an array with the given spacer.

This proposal works for any length of an array, even with one or two elements.

```js
var array = ['tea', 'milk', 'honey'],
    string = array.concat(array.splice(-2, 2).join(' and ')).join(', ');

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first grab all the values of the checked items and store them in an array. Then I would transform the array into a string using the join method based on how many items are in the array.

```
var addns= Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByName("addons")).filter(function(el) {
            return el.checked; 
          }).map(function(el){ return el.value});

        if(addns.length) {
            if(addns.length === 2) addns = addns.join(" and ");
            else if(addns.length > 2) {
            addns.splice(-2, 2, addns[addns.length-2]+ " and " + addns[addns.length -1]);
            addns = addns.join(", ")      
          }
          addns = "With " + addns; 
        }
```